# Conv3D in Keras with MXNet: error with tensor shape

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, mxnet

I implemented a 3D `CNN` in Keras with TensorFlow before which worked really fine. Now to speed up the training on multiple GPU's, I wanted to try `MXNet` with `Keras`. I expected that I didn't have to change a lot of the code apart from the "`channels_last`" to "channels_first" issue, but the program crashes at a Conv3D operation.

The keras.json file is, so it should be set up to run fine:

```
{
    "backend": "mxnet",
    "image_data_format": "channels_first",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32"
}
```

This is a small part which shows the error:

```py
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *

def SimpleInceptionBlock(input, num_kernels, kernel_init='he_normal', padding='same', bn_axis=1):
    tower1 = Conv3D(num_kernels, 1, padding=padding, kernel_initializer=kernel_init)(input)
    tower1 = BatchNormalization()(tower1)
    tower1 = ELU()(tower1)

    tower2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), padding=padding)(input)
    tower2 = Conv3D(num_kernels, 1, padding=padding, kernel_initializer=kernel_init)(tower2)
    tower2 = BatchNormalization()(tower2)
    tower2 = ELU()(tower2)

    output = concatenate([tower1, tower2], axis=bn_axis)
    return output


def TestNet(input_size=(1,64,64,64), num_class=7):
    bn_axis = 1

    img_input = Input(shape=input_size)

    filter1 = SimpleInceptionBlock(img_input, 16)
    # this runs fine, filter1.shape = (None, 32, 64, 64, 64)

    filter2 = SimpleInceptionBlock(filter1, 16)

    output = Conv3D(num_class, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax', kernel_initializer = kernel_init, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4))(filter2)
    model = Model(input=img_input, output=output)

    return model


model = TestNet()
```

The first call of "`SimpleInceptionBlock`" runs fine, with `filter1.shape = (None, 32, 64, 64)` as expected, but the second call yields the error message:

> Error in operator concat0: [15:40:58]
>   C:\Jenkins\workspace\mxnet-tag\mxnet\src\operator\nn\concat.cc:66:
>   Check failed: shape_assign(&(*in_shape)[i], dshape) Incompatible input
>   shape: expected [0,0,64,64,64], got [0,16,64,65,65]

Comment: If the same code runs fine with the Tensorflow backend, you should report the issue here: https://github.com/awslabs/keras-apache-mxnet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I reported it here: https://github.com/awslabs/keras-apache-mxnet/issues/240